# In full calendar JS, I'm want to display the event end date along with event title but, event end date is being displayed in milliseconds (i think)

Tags: javascript, json, fullcalendar, momentjs

I have the ajax code below for the calendar:

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'display_event.php',  
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function (response) {
        
   var result=response.data;
   $.each(result, function (i, item) {
       events.push({
           event_id: result[i].event_id,
           title: result[i].title,
           start: result[i].start,
           end: result[i].end,
           //color: result[i].color,
           url: result[i].url
       });  
   })
   var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
       defaultView: 'month',
        timeZone: 'local',
       editable: true,
       selectable: true,
       selectHelper: false,
       select: function(start, end) {
               //alert(start);
               //alert(end);
               $('#event_start_date').val(moment(start).format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
               $('#event_end_date').val(moment(end).format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
               $('#event_entry_modal').modal('show');
           },
          
       events: events,
       eventRender: function(event, element, view) { 
           element.find('.fc-title').append(" <b>" + event.end +"</b>");
           element.bind('click', function() {
           
                   alert(event.end);
               });
       }
       }); //end fullCalendar block 
     },//end success block
     error: function (xhr, status) {
     alert(response.msg);
     }
   });
```

I have appended "event.end" with the event title but the event.end is being displayed in milliseconds. I want it to show in YYYY-MM-DD as per my database and JSON data. I have checked the JSON data to be passing YYYY-MM-DD (2023-08-13).

My output is displayed as below. I want the event to be displayed as "GovernmentHoliday 2023-08-13".

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QyKsB.png)

The alert seem to be displaying correctly though

```
element.bind('click', function() {
           
                   alert(event.end);
               });
```

Comment: pls post the code of  `display_event.php` and the related db table schema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you concatenate the value of the Moment object it will [return the unix timestamp in milliseconds](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/unix-timestamp-milliseconds/). When you pass a Moment object to alert, its [`toString()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-string/) method is called.

Note that `event.end` will be `null` for events that have the same value for `start` and `end` (e.g. all day event on single day). You should check that `event.end` is not null before attempting to use it.

```js
eventRender: function (event, element) {
    if (event.end !== null) {
        element.find('.fc-title').append(" <b>" + event.end.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + "</b>");
    }
}
```

You appear to be using a rather old version of FullCalendar. You should consider switching to the vanilla JS version which removes the Moment and jQuery dependencies.